Optimize aggregate queries
I have a query like $products = Product::query()->where(...).... I want to read the maximum dimensions for my double range sliders something like:
    $dimensionLimits = [
        'width' => [
            'min' => $products->min('width'),
            'max' => $products->max('width')
        ],
        'height' => [
            'min' => $products->min('height'),
            'max' => $products->max('height')
        ],
        'depth' => [
            'min' => $products->min('depth'),
            'max' => $products->max('depth')
        ],
    ];

My problem that this is 6 relative slow queries. Is there a way to optimize this into a single query? I know it is possible by adding raw SQL, but is there a way to do it with Eloquent generated queries?

Product::query()     ->selectRaw('MIN(width) as min_width, MAX(width) as max_width, MIN(height) as min_height, MAX(height) as max_height, MIN(depth) as min_depth, MAX(depth) as max_depth')     ->first();

@francisco So there is no built-in solution in Eloquent, just raw SQL?

what you have done like Product::query()->min('width')->max('width')->min('height')... I think that is the other way

@francisco Can you add an answer?

shows same results and it's faster by this way? here is the link for the docs on min()/max() for  query builder..

To do it in raw SQL, use:
Product::query()->selectRaw('MIN(width) as min_width, MAX(width) as max_width, MIN(height) as min_height, MAX(height) as max_height, MIN(depth) as min_depth, MAX(depth) as max_depth')->get();


The main problem that I cannot reuse the $products variable this way. Later I use $products->paginate() but with the raw query it gives bad results.

Have any ->orderBy()? I've put first(), but use get(), to bring all results..

your aggregation query should be separate of your data query

@inf3rno, The above comment by kris gjika is correct.I have posted my answer,please check and let me know if it is working.

@krisgjika The product query contains additional wheres and orderby too. I rather moved the code into functions, so I can reuse them this way: Product::query()->where($categoriesFilter)->where($keywordsFilter). It is just minimal code duplication.


The main problem that I cannot reuse the $products variable this way.
Later I use $products->paginate() but with the raw query it gives bad
results

In this scenario you can do something like this to get both pagination() and aggregation results.
Step1 :- Fetch paginated records
$products = Product::query()->where(...);
$paginated_product = $products->paginate();

Step 2:- Fetch aggregated result-set
$maxMinDimensions = $products->selectRaw('MIN(width) as min_width, MAX(width) as max_width, MIN(height) as min_height, MAX(height) as max_height, MIN(depth) as min_depth, MAX(depth) as max_depth')->first();

